# How do I Join two tables together in SQLite that can be used in JAVA Sprint Boot?

Tags: java, sqlite

I am using a Movie Database that will link to the front-end of my website. i am using Java Spring Boot to link the Database. My question is, How can i join a Movies table and Reviews table>]?

```
    try {

        String getAllActorsbyMoviesidQuery = "SELECT * FROM  tblMovies JOIN tblReviews ON tblReviews.actor_id  = tblMovies.actor_id";
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(getAllReviewsbyMoviesidQuery);
```

Comment: If the problem _isn't_, as [forpas suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55745756/2096401), that `actor_id` seems an odd column to join on, can you [edit] the question to indicate **how/why** you think it isn't working? Do you get error messages? If you get output, how is it different from what you expect/want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining the 2 tables on `actor_id` is not probably the suitable way. 
I guess there exists inside `tblReviews` a column like `movie_id` that refers to the `id` column of the table `tblMovies`:

```
SELECT * FROM  tblMovies JOIN tblReviews ON tblReviews.movie_id  = tblMovies.id
```

change the column names to the actual ones.
If you want the reviews for a particular movie, then add a WHERE clause, like:

```
WHERE tblMovies.id = ?
```

or

```
WHERE tblMovies.title = ?
```

Comment: Thank You. this has helped me understand it better. :)